# hyperledger fabric block copying

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Is there a way to copy different aspects of a chain code (i.e. world state, keys, others attributes?) from one chain code to another? I'm experimenting at this point, but I can foresee a scenario where I need to change some go code & deploy.

Deployment will basically create a new chaincode with its own state. Suppose I want to access keys from previous chaincode. Do I need to keep track of all previous chaincode IDs in the fabric? Is there a way to consolidate all keys into the newly deployed chaincode?

Answer (score 1):

There are two capabilities in Fabric 1.0 that may help you.

1) Chaincode [upgrade](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4noah.html#upgrade). Let's say the first chaincode is version 1. If your new chaincode has the same name but you simply increment the version number, then upon instantiation the new chaincode will inherit the full state of the first chaincode. The first chaincode would no longer be invokable.

2) Chaincode to chaincode invocations.  The second chaincode can invoke the first chaincode using the [InvokeChaincode() API](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L80).
This could be done in the Init() function of the new chaincode at instantiation time, to read all the relevant state from the first chaincode and create associated state in the second chaincode. Alternatively, the second chaincode could invoke the first chaincode as needed during traditional invokes, to reference or copy over any state that is needed for a particular transaction.

Of course, to utilize solution #2 then you need correct query functions available on the first chaincode. If you don't have these in place, then you could use a combined solution. First, use solution #1 to upgrade the first chaincode to add the correct query functions that will be needed, and then use solution #2 to invoke these new query functions from your brand new chaincode.